# Tensorflow: How to get all variables from rnn_cell.BasicLSTM & rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a setup where I need to initialize an LSTM after the main initialization which uses `tf.initialize_all_variables()`. I.e. I want to call `tf.initialize_variables([var_list])`

Is there way to collect all the internal trainable variables for both:

- rnn_cell.BasicLSTM
- rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell

so that I can initialize **JUST** these parameters?

The main reason I want this is because I do not want to re-initialize some trained values from earlier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to use variable scope. The names of the variables within a scope will be prefixed with its name. Here is a short snippet:

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_nodes)

with tf.variable_scope("LSTM") as vs:
  # Execute the LSTM cell here in any way, for example:
  for i in range(num_steps):
    output[i], state = cell(input_data[i], state)

  # Retrieve just the LSTM variables.
  lstm_variables = [v for v in tf.all_variables()
                    if v.name.startswith(vs.name)]

# [..]
# Initialize the LSTM variables.
tf.initialize_variables(lstm_variables)
```

It would work the same way with `MultiRNNCell`.

EDIT: changed `tf.trainable_variables` to `tf.all_variables()`

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Didn't realize that `tf.trainable_variables()` respects scope, but I guess in hindsight it makes sense!

Comment: Would like to add that `tf.all_variables()` instead of `tf.trainable_variables()` would be a better choice. Mainly because there are things like optimizers that don't have trainable variables, which would however still need to be initialized.

Comment: You maybe should check for `v.name.startswith(vs.name + "/")` because there could be another scope with the same name prefix, e.g. "LSTM2".

Comment: it works but sometimes I wish the LSTM is set up differently to be consistent with all other kinds of variables in tensorflow

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [`tf.get_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#get_collection):

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_nodes)
with tf.variable_scope("LSTM") as vs:
  # Execute the LSTM cell here in any way, for example:
  for i in range(num_steps):
    output[i], state = cell(input_data[i], state)

  lstm_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope=vs.name)
```

(partly copied from Rafal's answer)

Note that the last line is equivalent to the list comprehension in Rafal's code.

Basically, tensorflow stores a global collection of variables, which can be fetched by either `tf.all_variables()` or `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES)`. If you specify `scope` (scope name) in the [`tf.get_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#get_collection) function, then you only fetch tensors (variables in this case) in the collection whose scopes are under the specified scope.

EDIT:
You can also use `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` to get trainable variables only. But since vanilla BasicLSTMCell does not initialize any non-trainable variable, both will be functionally equivalent. For a complete list of default graph collections, check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#GraphKeys) out.

Comment: This is way the better way than Rafal's solution :-)

Comment: Just like I commented above, you maybe should better use `tf.get_collection(..., scope=vs.name + "/")` because there could be another scope named "LSTM2" or so.